# Python String to Date?

Tags: python, odoo

Please help me to convert below string to date type.

130129:1007

[its means 2013/01/29 10:07am]

when I tried to write it in my database its gives below error.
DataError: date/time field value out of range: "130129:1007"

Comment: Do you want it to be a date or a datetime (date truncates the time of day)?  Also, google for: python strptime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('130129:1007', '%y%m%d:%H%M')
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 29, 10, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).